# Почему не видит обычный класс у scss module?

Tags: css, reactjs, scss, модули

есть класс `.welcome` определенный в module, он постоянно уникальный, так как это модули, например вот: `'Welcome_welcome__SRqBq'`

и есть обычный класс `show`, который добавляется динамически при скролле

**Вопрос:** как мне использовать в модуле оба класса по типу:

```
.welcome.show{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

если пишу так, то класс `show` не видит и стили не применяются

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

Перечисление классов для стилизации:

```css
.welcome, .show{
   opacity: 1;
}
```